# HTML5 video doesn't work in Firefox and IE when I use video files locally

Tags: html, video, html5-video

Maybe somebody had faced with such problem?
I just have tried to use Video-JS player.
First time I used the following markup:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" 
        width="640" height="264"
        poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
        data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
    <track kind="captions" src="captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" />
</video>
```

Everything was ok. Then I downloaded these three files - mp4, webm and ogv, and placed them locally into the directory of my site. Markup:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" 
  width="640" height="264"
  poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
  data-setup="{}">
      <source src="/Content/Images/Data/Media/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
      <source src="/Content/Images/Data/Media/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
      <source src="/Content/Images/Data/Media/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
      <track kind="captions" src="/Scripts/video-js/captions.vtt" srclang="en" 
            label="English" />
</video>
```

Now it works fine in Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox and IE. Before I tried to use the other HTML5 player - Leanpack, and I had faced with the same behaviour. What is cause of problem?

Comment: Are you using the file:// protocol instead of http:// ? If so that's not so anormal : a lot of things are different (streaming capacities for example) and not completely implemented for file:// sources.

Comment: @dystroy i just use a relative reference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server (even if it's localhost) needs to be set up to provide the correct mime types or the fussier browsers won't play back the files. [See dive into html5 for more information](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#video-mime-types).

Answer (score 1):

Change the file extension from .ogv to .ogg. It works well.

Answer (score 0):

Add the absolute path to the mp4 file and IE9 will play it. 
[See answer on video.js help guide from Jonas](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/1339-can-get-to-work-in-everything-but-ie9)