# Video background doesn't work (html, css, js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

i'm working on a code that create a video background in loop.
Unfortunately the code doesn't work if I change the video source, because I copied the code from a tutorial online: http://codepen.io/bldng/pen/biGJx
I need help to solve the problem.
This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>videosfondo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

  <video class="video" autoplay loop>
  <source src="video/video.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
<div class="text">prova</div>

  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

  <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is not working in your code? Video not playing?

Comment: Working for me on Chrome and Safari - what is the issue ?

Comment: Check your console for errors

Comment: On FF there is a issue with your media -> "Specified "type" attribute of "video/mp4" is not supported. Load of media resource http://cl.ly/2F382N3n2S0k/.mp4 failed."

Comment: Derek, yes video not playing!
Damian the video not playing also on chrome, and i've tried to load also mp4 and other files and the issue is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the link of codepen given by you in Chrome, FF and IE. Its working fine in Chrome but in IE and FF its not working. Below are some of the link/suggestions you can try which might work for you.

[VIDEO FILES MUST BE SERVED WITH THE PROPER MIME TYPE!](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#video-mime-types)

Check [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630835/html5-video-doesnt-work-in-firefox-and-ie-when-i-use-video-files-locally) for the source.